# An error in json data processing "string indices must be integers"

Tags: python, json

I want to read data by key, but below error is in question

```
    print(data[0]['user_id'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My code :

```
with open("AccInformation.json") as file:
    data = json.loads(file.read())
    print(data[0]['user_id'])
```

My example json file :

```
[
    "{\"user_id\": 88387467586, \"firstName\": \"Murat\", \"lastName\": \"KO\\u00c7\", \"email\": \"vehbikoc@kocholding.com.tr\", \"username\": \"kocholding\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"Y29K-G6LF-MRDI-PT5S-BZ1Q-VA4N\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 02:01:31 2021\"}",
    "{\"user_id\": 33233303603, \"firstName\": \"Sema\", \"lastName\": \"UZUN\", \"email\": \"sema12@gmail.com\", \"username\": \"semazen\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"ZW2G-7960-HPQA-5SKX-LTDJ-YBCE\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 14:42:39 2021\"}",
    "{\"user_id\": 86519529854, \"firstName\": \"Sema\", \"lastName\": \"UZUN\", \"email\": \"sema12@gmail.com\", \"username\": \"semazen\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"79DG-BNAZ-4IV3-OCKE-H5PM-UJ0T\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 15:42:37 2021\"}",
    "{\"user_id\": 51814237688, \"firstName\": \"Sema\", \"lastName\": \"UZUN\", \"email\": \"sema12@gmail.com\", \"username\": \"semazen\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"SLVG-F2C6-0QOB-5UJ1-AIHZ-78X4\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 22:46:48 2021\"}"
]
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your JSON file looks broken. It is a list of strings and not a list of objects. Whoever created this file should fix it. Then you can work with it.

Comment: Looks like you would need to `json.loads` those strings in your list again, because for some reason your json file stores string-literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is a json with a list of strings. You need to parse each of them again or fix your json.

```py
with open("AccInformation.json") as file:
   data = json.load(file)
   print(json.loads(data[0])['user_id'])
```

Or even better:

```py
with open() as file:
   data = [json.loads(it) for it in json.load(file)]
   print(data[0]['user_id'])
```

The [] syntax is called a list comprehension. Alltough I suggest you fix your json instead

Answer (score 1):

Your json file format is wrong, could you remove the "" around the maps and also remove the \ escaping the "" in the keys for your maps, so that instead of:

```
[
    "{\"user_id\": 88387467586, \"firstName\": \"Murat\", \"lastName\": \"KO\\u00c7\", \"email\": \"vehbikoc@kocholding.com.tr\", \"username\": \"kocholding\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"Y29K-G6LF-MRDI-PT5S-BZ1Q-VA4N\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 02:01:31 2021\"}",
    "{\"user_id\": 33233303603, \"firstName\": \"Sema\", \"lastName\": \"UZUN\", \"email\": \"sema12@gmail.com\", \"username\": \"semazen\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"ZW2G-7960-HPQA-5SKX-LTDJ-YBCE\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 14:42:39 2021\"}",
    "{\"user_id\": 86519529854, \"firstName\": \"Sema\", \"lastName\": \"UZUN\", \"email\": \"sema12@gmail.com\", \"username\": \"semazen\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"79DG-BNAZ-4IV3-OCKE-H5PM-UJ0T\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 15:42:37 2021\"}",
    "{\"user_id\": 51814237688, \"firstName\": \"Sema\", \"lastName\": \"UZUN\", \"email\": \"sema12@gmail.com\", \"username\": \"semazen\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"SLVG-F2C6-0QOB-5UJ1-AIHZ-78X4\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 22:46:48 2021\"}"
]
```

should be

```
[
    {"user_id": 88387467586, "firstName": "Murat", "lastName": "KOu00c7", "email": "vehbikoc@kocholding.com.tr", "username": "kocholding", "password": "123456789", "accountKEY": "Y29K-G6LF-MRDI-PT5S-BZ1Q-VA4N", "register_date": "Mon Aug 30 02:01:31 2021"},
    {"user_id": 33233303603, "firstName": "Sema", "lastName": "UZUN", "email": "sema12@gmail.com", "username": "semazen", "password": "123456789", "accountKEY": "ZW2G-7960-HPQA-5SKX-LTDJ-YBCE", "register_date": "Mon Aug 30 14:42:39 2021"},
    {"user_id": 86519529854, "firstName": "Sema", "lastName": "UZUN", "email": "sema12@gmail.com", "username": "semazen", "password": "123456789", "accountKEY": "79DG-BNAZ-4IV3-OCKE-H5PM-UJ0T", "register_date": "Mon Aug 30 15:42:37 2021"},
    {"user_id": 51814237688, "firstName": "Sema", "lastName": "UZUN", "email": "sema12@gmail.com", "username": "semazen", "password": "123456789", "accountKEY": "SLVG-F2C6-0QOB-5UJ1-AIHZ-78X4", "register_date": "Mon Aug 30 22:46:48 2021"}
]
```

Then it will work properly and you can access your data as follows:

```
data[0]["user_id" or indeed data[0].user_id
```

Comment: first of all thank you very much. I try to remove them but unfortunately it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a list of strings in your `AccInformation.json` file, and you are trying to access the the key `user_id` of a string, which is not possible because strings have integers as indexes. What you need to do is `json.loads(data[0])` first, which will deserialize the string into a python object, then you can access the key `user_id`.

It should be something like:

```
with open("AccInformation.json") as file:
    data = json.loads(file.read())
    account = json.loads(data[0])
    print(account["user_id"])
```

Another tip: You can pass a file to `json.load()`, so you don't need to call `file.read()`:

```
with open("AccInformation.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    account = json.loads(data[0])
    print(account["user_id"])
```

More about `json` lib and examples: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable reply, I am trying to edit it now

Answer (score 1):

If you have to stick with your file structure: (but please note this syntax is not a JSON file)

```
[
    "{\"user_id\": 88387467586, \"firstName\": \"Murat\", \"lastName\": \"KO\\u00c7\", \"email\": \"vehbikoc@kocholding.com.tr\", \"username\": \"kocholding\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"Y29K-G6LF-MRDI-PT5S-BZ1Q-VA4N\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 02:01:31 2021\"}",
    "{\"user_id\": 33233303603, \"firstName\": \"Sema\", \"lastName\": \"UZUN\", \"email\": \"sema12@gmail.com\", \"username\": \"semazen\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"ZW2G-7960-HPQA-5SKX-LTDJ-YBCE\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 14:42:39 2021\"}",
    "{\"user_id\": 86519529854, \"firstName\": \"Sema\", \"lastName\": \"UZUN\", \"email\": \"sema12@gmail.com\", \"username\": \"semazen\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"79DG-BNAZ-4IV3-OCKE-H5PM-UJ0T\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 15:42:37 2021\"}",
    "{\"user_id\": 51814237688, \"firstName\": \"Sema\", \"lastName\": \"UZUN\", \"email\": \"sema12@gmail.com\", \"username\": \"semazen\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"SLVG-F2C6-0QOB-5UJ1-AIHZ-78X4\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 22:46:48 2021\"}"
]
```

Using regex you could do this in order to transform at runtime your current file into a proper json file: (Works as is)

```
with open("AccInformation.json") as file:
    cleaned = file.read().replace(r"(?<!\\)", "")
    cleaned = '{ \n   "data": ' + cleaned + '\n }'
    pre_data = json.loads(cleaned)
    data = [json.loads(x) for x in pre_data.get('data')]
    print(data[0]['user_id'])
>>> 88387467586
```

Otherwise please refactor your code so your json file looks  something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {\"user_id\": 88387467586, \"firstName\": \"Murat\", \"lastName\": \"KO\\u00c7\", \"email\": \"vehbikoc@kocholding.com.tr\", \"username\": \"kocholding\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"Y29K-G6LF-MRDI-PT5S-BZ1Q-VA4N\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 02:01:31 2021\"},
        {\"user_id\": 33233303603, \"firstName\": \"Sema\", \"lastName\": \"UZUN\", \"email\": \"sema12@gmail.com\", \"username\": \"semazen\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"ZW2G-7960-HPQA-5SKX-LTDJ-YBCE\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 14:42:39 2021\"},
        {\"user_id\": 86519529854, \"firstName\": \"Sema\", \"lastName\": \"UZUN\", \"email\": \"sema12@gmail.com\", \"username\": \"semazen\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"79DG-BNAZ-4IV3-OCKE-H5PM-UJ0T\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 15:42:37 2021\"},
        {\"user_id\": 51814237688, \"firstName\": \"Sema\", \"lastName\": \"UZUN\", \"email\": \"sema12@gmail.com\", \"username\": \"semazen\", \"password\": \"123456789\", \"accountKEY\": \"SLVG-F2C6-0QOB-5UJ1-AIHZ-78X4\", \"register_date\": \"Mon Aug 30 22:46:48 2021\"}
    ]
}
```

Then you can call as expected:

```
with open("AccInformation.json") as file:
    data = json.loads(file.read())["data"]
    print(data[0]['user_id'])
```